# ipvsadm rewriting virtual service ip address

Tags: ipvs

```
$ sudo ipvsadm -A -u 127.10.5.5:1293                                                                                                                     
$ sudo ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
UDP  localhost:1293 wlc
```

Why does it replace `127.10.5.5` with `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh nevermind, I just need to add `--numeric`: `sudo ipvsadm -L --numeric`